# Steam Sharing Library Help

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

It is possible to have Steam Family Sharing set up so me and my child can both play the same game at the same time? As of now it says:

> An error occurred while updating Red Faction Guerilla Steam Edition (shared library locked)

Is there a possible fix or am I stuck with it?

Answer (score -2):

From the stream FAQs page:

> To enable Family Library Sharing, first be sure you >have Steam Guard security enabled via Steam >Settings > Account in the Steam Client. Then enable the sharing feature via Settings > Family,
>   (or in Big Picture mode, Settings > Family Library >Sharing,) where you'll also authorize specific computers and users to share.

So, just make sure you flow the steps. I would assume you missed enabling Family Library Sharing.

Comment: this is factually wrong

Comment: What is wrong with it? I’ll try and fix it

Comment: Family Library Sharing does not allow 2 players to play at the same time, that is what the question asks

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood the question